# Can Trump legally sell stocks on Friday, tweet about imposing tariffs on Sunday and then buy more of the stocks back on Monday?

Tags: united-states, finance, securities, sec, insider-trading

Trump could have made a lot of money by selling stocks before tweeting about imposing tariffs on China and then buying more of them back when the price of the stocks has dropped. Would this fall under the ban on insider trading, or does insider trading only apply to confidential information about companies?

Comment: This would qualify as a pump and dump scheme, and would be illegal as a result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_dump

Comment: @Allure an element of pump and dump is making misleading statements.  There is no misleading statement here.

Comment: @phoog It doesn't have to be misleading. It just has to be for the purpose of inflating the stock then dumping it.

Comment: @Putvi every description of pump and dump I've seen stresses or at least mentions misleading statements.  An example is https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answerspumpdumphtm.html.  Anyway, the hypothetical act here does not meet the definition of pump and dump on a couple of additional counts, since the manipulation of the price is downward, not upward.  This is a good example of why questions should not be answered in comments.

Comment: @phoog yes, it is commonly used that way. I just meant in terms of criminal prosecutions, they would charge you either way. Not everything in life is going to meet some Wikipedia or sec site Q and A for every instance.

Comment: @Putvi of course.

Comment: @phoog Sorry if you thought I meant it as a dig. I just meant don't go to jail over trying to be technical over wording.

Comment: @Putvi no, I didn't think it was a dig.  In fact, there was supposed to be more to that comment, which I wasn't done writing.  I must have added it by mistake.  Your point agrees with mine, though I may not have made mine clear: *if* the hypothetical act here is illegal, it is indeed not "as a result" of its fitting some category of scam, but because it violates a prohibition against trading on the basis of nonpublic information, or market manipulation, or fraud (although I don't see fraud here), etc. The statutes I've seen do not describe particular scams in detail, much less name them.

Comment: Do answers need to include the fact that Trump is apparently above the law?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no statutory definition of insider trading, and the question of who is included is answered by [the SEC](https://www.investor.gov/additional-resources/general-resources/glossary/insider-trading). It includes "Government employees who traded based on confidential information they learned because of their employment with the government". Under [5 USC 2105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/2105), POTUS is an "employee", though that is w.r.t. Title 5 and insider trading laws are under Title 15. But as it happens, the [Title 15 definition](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/78u-1#h_2_A_i) of "executive branch employee" assigns the Title 5 definition of "employee" to "executive branch employee" and explicitly lists POTUS.

[Pub. L. No. 112-105, §§ 9(b)(1)](https://www.congress.gov/112/plaws/publ105/PLAW-112publ105.pdf) explicitly says

> Executive   branch   employees,  judicial  officers,  and  judicial 
>   employees  are  not  exempt  from  the  insider  trading  prohibitions
>   arising  under  the  securities  laws,  including  section  10(b)  of 
>   the  Securities  Exchange Act of 1934 and Rule 10b–5 thereunder.

Insider trading laws are not limited to "information about company X", they are framed in terms of non-public information, which could include information about a country: "no executive branch employee may use nonpublic information derived from such person’s position as an executive branch employee  or  gained  from  the  performance  of  such  person’s  official  responsibilities  as  a  means  for  making  a  private  profit".

Comment: Technically in this scenario trump didn't "learn" something because of his employment with the government.  He choose to take an action in his role as an employee.  In theory he doesn't even need to take any action other then tweeting something, The threatened tariffs don't  have to be imposed for him to benefit.  I still think this would count as insider trading, from my limited understanding of the relevant precedents, but your answer as it stands now does not demonstrate that making threats in the role of a company to affect the market would count as insider trading.

Answer (score -2):

I take the relevant part of your question to be whether a president can break the law, taking it as a given that the stock manipulation you describe is illegal if proven.

The short answer is yes, the president can, has, and will again break the law. The president is above the law.

There are basically three ways the president can be removed from office:

1. forcibly by assassination, kidnapping, and similar violent actions;
2. by impeachment by the senate for crimes and misdemeanors, but there is no precedent for that;
3. by an application of the 25th amendment, if the president is incapacitated by a mental or physical illness; but there is no precedent for that.

None of these are realistic threats today to keep President Trump in check, suggesting that the crime you describe CAN be committed without sanction.

Comment: What is your basis for claiming that POTUS is above the law?

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clearly about whether such conduct was legal, and not about what would be the consequences if it is illegal.

Comment: I thought the question had multiple interpretations since it pretty much asks "Can Trump legally [action that clearly breaks the law for non-presidents]?" POTUS is above the law according to today's ruling on two articles of impeachment that document actions that 'break' the constitution.